# Share or include variables for specific tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```yaml
# Some tasks which uses the default user specified in group_vars/all

- name: Check if installer exists
  win_stat:
    path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
  vars:
    # TODO Reuse variables
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: "{{ network_share_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ network_share_user_pw }}"
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  register: installer_info

- name: Run installation
  win_package:
    path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
    product_id: '...'
    arguments: '/q'
  vars:
    # TODO Reuse variables
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: "{{ network_share_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ network_share_user_pw }}"
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  when: installer_info.stat.exists == True

# Some other tasks
```

The user for the usual tasks are defined in `group_vars/all`, but if I need to access a network share I have to use a generic user (see playbook vars above).

**How can I share this block of variables *only* for those specific "network drive" tasks? Not affecting other tasks in the playbook.**

It would be best to put the variables in a separate file and include them in the tasks like with `include_vars` or `vars_files`. But these commands cant be used for specific tasks, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be no general solution, I looked for alternatives that at least cover this use case.

**Approach 1:**
Using a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) and defining the variables for the whole block:

```yaml
- block:
  - name: Check if installer exists
    win_stat:
      path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
    register: installer_info

  - name: Run installation
    win_package:
      path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
      product_id: '...'
      arguments: '/q'
    when: installer_info.stat.exists == True
  vars:
      ansible_become: yes
      ansible_become_method: runas
      ansible_become_user: "{{ network_share_user }}"
      ansible_become_password: "{{ network_share_user_pw }}"
      ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

---

**Approach 2:** Going a little further (if you have multiple similar blocks). Use separate file and include it:

File `install_software.yml`:

```yaml
- block:
  - name: Check if installer exists
    win_stat:
      path: "{{ path }}"
    register: installer_info

  - name: Run installation
    win_package:
      path: "{{ path }}"
      product_id: "{{ product_id }}"
      arguments: "{{ arguments }}"
    when: installer_info.stat.exists == True
  vars:
      ansible_become: yes
      ansible_become_method: runas
      ansible_become_user: "{{ network_share_user }}"
      ansible_become_password: "{{ network_share_user_pw }}"
      ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

Main playbook:

```yaml
- import_tasks: install_software.yml
  vars:
    path: \\path_to_installer\installer1.exe
    product_id: '...'
    arguments: '/q'

- import_tasks: install_software.yml
  vars:
    path: \\path_to_installer\installer2.exe
    product_id: '...'
    arguments: '/q'
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```yaml
- name: "Your Playbook"
  hosts:
    - your_host

  vars:
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: "{{ network_share_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ network_share_user_pw }}"
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only

  tasks:
  - name: Check if installer exists
    win_stat:
      path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
    register: installer_info

  - name: Run installation
    win_package:
      path: \\path_to_installer\installer.exe
      product_id: '...'
      arguments: '/q'
    when: installer_info.stat.exists == True
```

Comment: That would affect other tasks in the playbook respectively role. I am looking for a way to assign that variables to specific tasks only. Those tasks are also scattered over different roles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with ansible. [The guide about using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) states that about scoping:

> Ansible has 3 main scopes:
>
> Global: this is set by config, environment
> variables and the command line Play: each play and contained
> structures, vars entries (vars; vars_files; vars_prompt), role
> defaults and vars. Host: variables directly associated to a host, like
> inventory, include_vars, facts or registered task outputs

Comment: That's unfortunate. I know the scopes. I thought maybe there was another way.